# Ansible and Playbook. How to convert shell commands into yaml syntax?

Tags: ubuntu, syntax, yaml, vagrant, ansible

I'm a newbie in Ansible and I don't understand how all people easily write shell commands in the Ansible/YAML syntax. May be I've missed a page from the documentation where it is explained well.

For example: What do I need to write in my `playbook.yml` if I want to perform these commands in my remote machines:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo apt-key adv –recv-keys –keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 0xcbcb082a1bb943db
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://mariadb.biz.net.id//repo/5.5/ubuntu precise main'
```

I think it would be something like this:

```
- name: install mariadb
  apt: ...
  sudo: yes
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As raw shell command [modules](http://docs.ansible.com/list_of_commands_modules.html) will do the trick for plain translation of bash scripts. They will rarely end up to be idempotent actions. They can not be run twice without producing errors.

The Ansible way of doing this is to use the appropriate modules, in your case

- [apt_key](http://docs.ansible.com/apt_key_module.html) : add the gpg key
- [apt_repository](http://docs.ansible.com/apt_repository_module.html) : install the repository
- [apt](http://docs.ansible.com/apt_module.html) : install the package

A sample for [mariadb](https://www.blueleftistconstructor.com/2013/04/28/mariadb-adding-apt-gpg-key-when-using-ansible/)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is [Ansible Modules](http://docs.ansible.com/modules_by_category.html)!) This is actually what I need.
After quick search, I think my commands will be similar to:

```
-raw: sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
-raw: apt-key adv –recv-keys –keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 0xcbcb082a1bb943db
 etc..
```

Comment: this will cause the commands to run every single time you run the playbook on that server causing possible errors or failures on future runs. This should never be used except when a module is not available.