# how to get commands from ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

Is there a simple way how to get back what precisely ansible script(playbook) is trying to do?

E.g. I have

```yaml
- name: Install required packages
  yum: name={{item}} state=present
  with_items:
    - nmp
  become: True
```

And I want to get:

```
sudo yum install nmp
```

That said, I want to know what commands (OS level) ansible is running.
Basically, I need the reverse process to: [Ansible and Playbook. How to convert shell commands into yaml syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21005290/ansible-and-playbook-how-to-convert-shell-commands-into-yaml-syntax)

Comment: Just read the code: [`yum.py`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/packaging/os/yum.py).

Comment: Verbose `-vvvv`

Comment: guys(@techraf, @spinkus), the question whether there is a easy was how to get the commands - not crawling through of tons of logs from -vvvv, or reading code. I need that for 100 commands in ansible playbook

Comment: But Ansible only sometimes runs external commands (actually overall in pretty rare cases), it's mostly Python code and Python libraries.

Comment: interesting point @techraf - so you are saying there is no simple "translation" from modules like file (http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/file_module.html) to the OS level command? Only modules like command (http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/command_module.html) - which just run shell + command itself can be "translated"  - Do I understand it correctly?

Comment: Yes, you understand it correctly. It's even more complicated as a single module (like `yum`) behaves differently depending on parameters and installed libraries. Other modules must also handle different OS types, etc.

Comment: @techraf - write it as a answer - i believe it is valid one

Answer (score 5):

Summarizing here the central points from comments above [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43542544/how-to-get-commands-from-ansible#comment74138098_43542544)[[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43542544/how-to-get-commands-from-ansible#comment74140547_43542544).

Ansible rarely runs external commands, it's mostly Python code & Python libraries being used to control hosts.  Therefor, Ansible's "translation" isn't necessarily converting `yum` ([Ansible module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/yum_module.html)) usage into `yum` (CLI) invocations.

While you may be able to depend on the output, in some cases, by parsing for command sequences in the output of `ansible-playbook -vvv foo.yml` - the implementation would be flaky at best.

I'd encourage you to keep discussing on this thread what you're trying to accomplish.  It's likely there is already a solution, and someone can point you to a tool that already exists.